# jade printf-like number formatting

Tags: pug

How can I control the formatting of numbers in Jade template?

Sample code:

```
  for item in issue.item
   tr
    td.utilityValue #{item.$.value}
    td.utilityUtil #{item.$.evaluation * utilitySpace.weightmultiplyer}
```

I want the numbers to print with 2 significant digits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution I found; it works for Express 3:

1. Install sprintf by issuing:

   ```
   npm install sprintf
   ```
2. In app.js:

   ```
   app.locals.sprintf = require('sprintf').sprintf;

   app.locals.format = "%+1.0f";
   ```
3. In template.jade:

   ......
         td.utility #{sprintf(format, value)}
    ......